# Old-style plist linter

Tags: plist, lint, pbxproj, xcode-project

I am writing an application that generates .xcodeproj files. It's generated a .pbxproj file, however when opening it in Xcode, I get an error message, "cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed." and nothing more.

Is there a reliable application for syntax parsing old-style plists?

If it requires me to use low-level Cocoa APIs, I'm fine with that, but some pointers at least?

Comment: Isn't a plist just XML data? An XML validator, using [Apple's DTD](http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd) might be all you'd need...

Comment: didn't it get "corrupted" during a version controlling merge? which you could easily fix

Comment: @inspector-g Nope, it's an old style plist.

Comment: @benka It's not version control. It's a custom application I'm writing that mimics Xcode's create project feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [Xcodeproj](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj).

It's not a linter, but it may help you to understand why your project isn't being opened correctly.

You have a few options:

- Try to parse your project with Xcodeproj to see if it gives you more useful errors.
- You don't mention what language you're writing in, but if it's ruby, you could simply use the gem directly.
- See if you can call the CF calls directly. You'll note that the part of Xcodeproj that actually writes to the file calls this [c extension](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/blob/9f1fd5586cfc6ee084fc068a0d229885e33d00b7/ext/xcodeproj/xcodeproj_ext.c) which simply uses [CFPropertyListWriteToStream](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFPropertyListRef/Reference/reference.html).

This all assumes that your problem is one that could actually be solved by a linter. If your formatting is correct but you're writing values that somehow confuse Xcode then these suggestions may not apply, although I do think reading through the Xcodeproj source would help you.